# JQuery post return view with angular code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to use $.ajax to retrieve data using post request. The request goes to a ASP.NET MVC controller which returns a view which content is generated by angular.js ng-repeat. Then I am setting recievied html to a div on a page but angular is not working for me (it is not invoking directives like {{variable}}). What is a proper way to have angular-generated page displayed without reloading whole page?

Comment: Why are you not using angular view template and only return data to pass to the view? Please show some code

Comment: @charlietfl What I want to achieve is to give user some more details about an entry in a table. After he presses the row I pass JSON string via post request which is then passed via viewmodel to a view I am later returning. Then, I want to get whole table back and replace the existing table on the page.

Comment: Well you can use `$compile` but I would suggest you are deviating from the norm by having server generate the html for you. It sounds like you are building your app with a jQuery style ajax approach and should consider only using your back end as a data api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.bootstrap(A, ['B']);`

`A` : your document or an ID of your div in which your angular-html code resides

`B` : the controller which will manipulate your angular-html

The problem is that angular does not automatically recognize the newly loaded html-codes he should manipulate. By this manner, you should tell it that there is a newly added html-code